# Tomcat - отображение загруженных файлов на странице

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet, spring-boot, rest

Всем привет. приложение на Tomcat, SpringBoot, Angular (тестовая машина виндовая)
Задача стандартная загрузить на сервер, сохранить, отобразить.
Есть страница для загрузки фоток на сервер. Фотки загружаются нормально в файловую систему с пазом "Е://path//to//files//img.jpg".
И вот вопрос в том что: как мне их потом достать из этого паза "Е://path//to//files//img.jpg" и отобразить на странице.
Статический контент из "resources" берется и отображается

На некотором ресурсе нашел решение для томката [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/1812356#1812356) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516387/how-i-save-and-retrieve-an-image-on-my-server-in-a-java-webapp) но оно не сработало (или я его не понял)

```
<Context docBase="Е://path//to//files" path="/files" />
```

и потом это не отображется

```
<img src="/files/img.jpg">
```

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И снова всем привет. Проблема решена, посредством настройки спринга в обход *web.xml* (в данной ситуации web.xml не используется), оригинал решения [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288643/serve-dynamically-changing-static-content-with-spring-boot)

Код решения:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    static String IMAGE_DIR = "E://path//to//files//";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + IMAGE_DIR);
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
}
```

Далее в методе который сохраняет это дело паз пишем такой:

```
private static String PATH_FOR_UPLOADED = "E://path//to//files//";
```

а путь который будет храниться в БД такой:

```
private static String PATH_FOR_DATABASE = "./files/";
```

сохраняем как:

```
save(PATH_FOR_DATABASE + "any/else/path/" + "img.jpg")
```

ну и достаем, соответственно:

```
<img src="./files/any/alse/path/img.jpg">
```

*PS/ В принципе можно попытаться еще немного подшаманить: все эти пазы прописать в пропертях, что бы можно было их менять без перекомпиляции, но с редеплоем...*